# SSRS not using MSA or gMSA account on Domain

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, logins, reporting, service-accounts

I am trying to install SSRS on a new server to report on our new database server and want to use a MSA account on our domain (server is on our domain) but I keep getting errors when trying to start SSRS as the first step to installation.

This is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service SQLServerReportingServices on computer 'MYSSRSSERVERNAME-NOTREALNAME'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not start due to a logon failure
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
> at ReportServicesConfigUI.Panels.ConfigurationPanelWithErrors.StartOrStopServiceTask(Boolean start, String serviceName)

I have tried a domain account and that works, so it has something to do with the MSA account.

Event Viewer states the failure reason as `Unknown user name or bad password`. I never set a password for the MSA account as I used MSA GUI to set the password and it never prompted me to create one. The MSA account has logon on service permissions and is a domain user. I have added the account to local administrators groups to test but that still didn't work.

Anyway to resolve this?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/173792/150011)